# I can't get the patched regions of a citrus fruit using Otsu method with the Green channel on opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to get the patched regions of a citrus fruit using Otsu method with opencv. According to this paper: https://www.intechopen.com/books/agricultural-robots-fundamentals-and-applications/multimodal-classification-of-mangoes/ these authors were using the Green channel (G) to get the patches regions of mangoes:

[image]

I'm doing the same but usign lemons but I can't get those regions of my lemon.

This is my input image:

[image]

First I read the image and I'm calling to a function to show the image:

```
def show(img, titulo):
    plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
    plt.title(titulo)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

#read img
file = "lemons/bad/bad_5.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(file)
#convert from BGR to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
original = image
show(image, "original img "+str(image.shape))
```

Then I Added a blur filter:

```
#(blur) filter
image = cv2.blur(image,(31,31),0)
show(image, "img with BLUR")
```

Convert to HSV:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#get hsv channels
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
show(s, "channel S of HSV")
```

[image]

Then I added the Otsu's method:

```
#OTSU
_, thr = cv2.threshold(s, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
show(thr, "Binarized image with the OTSU method")
```

[image]

Finally I put this Otsu mask to  my original image:

```
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=thr)
show(result, "Lemon Segmented")
```

[image]

From here, with this only hole there is not problems because I'm getting the entire image.

According the research of the below URL https://www.intechopen.com/books/agricultural-robots-fundamentals-and-applications/multimodal-classification-of-mangoes/ it says that to isolate the patched regions, we should get the Green channel:

```
image = gray
B,green_ch,R = cv2.split(result)
show(green_ch, "Green channel 'G'")
```

This is the output:

[image]

Here there is a notary visualization of the two patched regions but when I use this channel to apply Otsu method, there is not results instead of I'm getting black holes:

```
_, thr = cv2.threshold(green_ch, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
show(thr, "OTSU with Green channel")
```

[image]

Result:

```
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=thr)
show(result, "Lemon Segmented")
```

[image]

As we can see the two patched regions are not segmented using the green channel. I tryed using the HSL color space but there is not good results. My idea is detect this patched and the get the color histogram to then train a classifier using those features.

I left this second image were I was testing the code:

[image]

Well guys I would like to see your suggestions to try to get the same result the paper of above, any I idea I will apreciate it.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you sure they used otsu's on the whole image like that? Otsu's separates an image into two pieces that have as large of a difference as possible. If you include the background then the two pieces will always be the background and the fruit. On the bright side, you've already shown that otsu's is good at getting rid of the background. If you use otsu's a second time on just the fruit it should yield good results.

Comment: Hi @lan Chu by the moment I never have tested another method different of Otsu, I would like to see one example of what you say. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I inverted the second mask to get just the defect areas.

Once you use otsu's the first time it'll give you back a mask that separates the foreground (the fruit) and the background. You can use otsu's a second time on the masked area to get another mask that separates out the dark spots on the fruit.

Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't have a simple way of running otsu's on just a masked area. However, otsu's is just looking for thresholds on the pixel intensity histogram that create the greatest interparty variance. Since this histogram is all proportional, we can force otsu's to run on just the masked area by making all of the unmasked pixels match the histogram propotions.

I converted to HSV and used the saturation channel to separate the fruit from the background.

[image]

[image]

I then used the histogram to replicate the pixel proportions on the unmasked pixels of the hue channel.

Hue Before

[image]

Hue After

[image]

Then I run otsu's a second time on the hue channel.

[image]

Now to get the final mask, we just bitwise_and the first and second masks together (and do an opening and closing operation to clean up little holes)

[image]

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

# apply histogram
def applyHist(gray, mask, hist):
    # get cumulative distribution
    cumulative = [];
    total = 0;
    for val in hist:
        total += val;
        cumulative.append(total);

    # apply to each pixel not in max
    positions = np.where(mask != 255);
    for a in range(len(positions[0])):
        # choose value
        rand = random.randint(0, cumulative[-1]);
        index = 0;
        while rand > cumulative[index]:
            index += 1;

        # apply
        y = positions[0][a];
        x = positions[1][a];
        gray[y,x] = index;

# load image
img = cv2.imread("lemon.png");

# hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv);

# use the saturation channel for the first mask
s = cv2.GaussianBlur(s, (5,5), 0);
_, mask = cv2.threshold(s, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);

# grab positions from mask and make histogram
positions = np.where(mask == 255);
hist = [0 for a in range(256)];
for a in range(len(positions[0])):
    y = positions[0][a];
    x = positions[1][a];
    pix = h[y,x];
    hist[pix] += 1;

# opencv doesn't have a way to just let you otsu on a mask...
# eheheheheheh, AHAHAHAHAHA
# LET'S JUST MAKE THE REST OF THE IMAGE MATCH THE HISTOGRAM
applyHist(h, mask, hist);

# otsu the image
h = cv2.GaussianBlur(h, (5,5), 0);
_, second_mask = cv2.threshold(h, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);
second_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(second_mask); # just get the defects

# combine with first mask
final_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, second_mask);

# opening and closing to get rid of small holes
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8);

# closing
final_mask = cv2.dilate(final_mask, kernel, iterations = 2);
final_mask = cv2.erode(final_mask, kernel, iterations = 2);

# opening
final_mask = cv2.erode(final_mask, kernel, iterations = 2);
final_mask = cv2.dilate(final_mask, kernel, iterations = 2);

# mask the image
cropped = np.zeros_like(img);
cropped[final_mask == 255] = img[final_mask == 255];

# show image
cv2.imshow("image", img);
cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped);
cv2.imshow("final", final_mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Hi @lan Chu I think that you did a great example of how apply Otsu's method by second time, but what I want is get the patched regions no the entire image with the two holes, here is an example https://imgur.com/a/VlOOt8n I want to do the same as this paper https://www.intechopen.com/books/agricultural-robots-fundamentals-and-applications/multimodal-classification-of-mangoes/  only get the patched region. Do you thing that this is a good idea? to then get features using the color histogram descriptor. I will apreciate if you have one example according to ti. Thanks

Comment: if you only want the patches you can invert the second mask

Comment: are you trying to classify defects? The color histogram descriptors are used to train a neural net to classify defects. If you just want to get the patches they used the exact same method of thresholding twice except they used their "Valley Emphasis Method" instead of Otsu.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to classify defects in the skin of the lemon, then should I invert this `second_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(second_mask);` can you update the code.. I was searching a code to implement the "Valley Emphasis Method" in python but  I did not find anything

Comment: Do you thing that with this approach we could get the same results that the "Valley Emphasis Method"?

Comment: Try it and see if it works for you. You won't get the exact same results using Otsu's as compared to a different thresholding method. If you want it to be the same then use their method. They detail out their entire process and methodology so you can replicate what they do with a bit of work.

Comment: ok, @Ian Chu thank you very much for your generous help, god bless you! keep it up. If you have any other contribution don't forget to share here or send an email creatorpart@gmail.com thanks so much.