# To get the center mask from an image of masks using Python3 and opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose I have these sets of images:

[image]

I want to take the center coordinate mask, i.e., the circular one which has the cell:

[image]

To finally isolate the cell

[image]

How to achieve these using Python3 and opencv?

Comment: That cell looks really different from the other masked objects. Do you have control over how you obtain that mask or are you just being given the masked image after someone else does the processing? If you do have control, are you ok with changing the method for creating the mask? Can you share the code you used to get the mask?

Comment: @IanChu check this code here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RH-rTRhhg4aqwuXNB4IZ6WP69-e56F2k?usp=sharing

Comment: I only need to extract the image that contains the center cell. I am okay with changing the code, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you're using otsu's method for making the mask. Is this because you don't trust the color to be consistent? If you still want an automated method of creating the mask, and you think that there will always be a mix of the target cell and the faded cells, you can run otsu's twice and it should get the target cell (plus that speckly red bit on the right). My lunch break is ending so here's a link to an answer showing how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66234503/i-cant-get-the-patched-regions-of-a-citrus-fruit-using-otsu-method-with-the-gre/66236132#66236132.

Comment: Ok cool, let me see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Concept

1. Detect the contours of the objects.
2. Loop through the contours and find the one that encloses the center of the image.
3. Using that contours, create a mask for the image and mask the image.

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 0, 50)
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, None, iterations=1)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, None, iterations=1)
    return img_erode

def get_masked(img):
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    center = h // 2, w // 2
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100:
            if cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, center, False) > 0:
                mask = np.zeros((h, w), 'uint8')
                cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255, -1) 
                return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

img = cv2.imread("blobs.png")
cv2.imshow("img_processed", get_masked(img))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### The Output

[image]

#### The Explanation

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function to process the image into a binary image that will allow optimal results when detecting the contours of the image:

```
def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 0, 50)
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, None, iterations=1)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, None, iterations=1)
    return img_erode
```

3. Define a function that will loop though the contours of the image *(using the `process` function defined before to process the image)*, and for every contour with contour area greater than `100` *(to filter out noise)*, check if the center of the image is inside the contour *(done by checking if the result from calling the `cv2.pointPolygonTest` returns a positive number)*, create the mask, mask the image and return the masked image:

```
def get_masked(img):
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    center = h // 2, w // 2
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100:
            if cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, center, False) > 0:
                mask = np.zeros((h, w), 'uint8')
                cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255, -1) 
                return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

4. Finally, read in your image, apply the `get_masked` function define before and show the image:

```
img = cv2.imread("blobs.png")
cv2.imshow("img_processed", get_masked(img))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```